# Need to remove Value and Count from Powershell JSON nested object

Tags: powershell

In powershell I'm trying to convert CSV file to JSON with nested array of Size object by grouping products. In code below $ProductLines come from CSV file as powershell object.

```
 $UniqueProducts = $ProductLines | Group-Object -Property 'ProductNumber' | ForEach-Object {    

    $SizeObj = ($_.Group | Select-Object -Property `
      @{name="SizeCode"; Expression = {$_.Sizes}}, @{name="UPC"; Expression = {$_.UPCNo}} `
    )
    #$SizeObj | ConvertTo-Json -depth 10 | Out-File "C:\POWERSHELL\Sizes.txt"

    $_.Group | Select-Object -Property ProductNumber, ProductName, `
         @{name="Sizes"; Expression = {$SizeObj}} -Unique
  }

$UniqueProducts | ConvertTo-Json -depth 10 | Out-File "C:\POWERSHELL\UniqueProducts.txt"
```

The above code produces JSON file with below structure with additional layer **value:** and **Count:**

```
[
    {
        "ProductNumber":  "EBAGS101-00008",
        "ProductName":  "EBAGS101",
        "Sizes":  {
                      "value":  [
                                    {
                                        "SizeCode":  "XS",
                                        "UPC":  "201112291509"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "SizeCode":  "S",
                                        "UPC":  "201112291510"
                                    }
                                ],
                      "Count":  2
                  }
    },
    {
        "ProductNumber":  "EBAGS101-001",
        "ProductName":  "EBAGS101",
        "Sizes":  {
                      "value":  [
                                    {
                                        "SizeCode":  "XS",
                                        "UPC":  ""
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "SizeCode":  "S",
                                        "UPC":  "098617106215"
                                    }
                                ],
                      "Count":  2
                  }
    }
]
```

How can I remove **value** and **Count** layer from my result. When I output just $SizeObj it doesn't have value and Count, I'm not sure how **value** and **Count** ends up in $UniquProducts. In my end result I'm trying to create SizeObj in the below format (without value and Count):

```
  "Sizes":   [
        {
            "SizeCode":  "XS",
            "UPC":  "201112291509"
        },
        {
            "SizeCode":  "S",
            "UPC":  "201112291510"
        }
    ]
```

**UPDATE:** using answer provided by @RoadRunner here is the modified solution with csv source; where $ProductLines is converted Powershell object from csv file:

```
$Products = New-Object -TypeName System.Collections.ArrayList
$ProductLines | Group-Object -Property 'ProductNumber' | ForEach-Object {
  $SizeRanges = New-Object -TypeName System.Collections.ArrayList
  foreach ($object in $_.Group) {
    $SizeVal = [PSCustomObject]@($object | Select-Object -Property `
        @{name="SizeCode"; Expression = {$_.Sizes}}, `
        @{name="UPC"; Expression = {$_.UPCNo}}`
      )
      $SizeRanges.AddRange($SizeVal)|Out-Null
  }
  $grp = $_.Group[0];
  $product =  [PSCustomObject]@{
      ProductNumber = $grp.ProductNumber
      ProductName = $grp.ProductName
      Sizes = $SizeRanges
  }
  $products.Add($product)|Out-Null
} | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 3 | Out-File -FilePath output.json
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just rebuild the JSON with the properties you want to keep.

First you can get the JSON data with [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-7) and [`ConvertFrom-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json?view=powershell-7). Then you can iterate each JSON object, creating a new [`PSCustomObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.pscustomobject?view=pscore-6.2.0) which keeps the `ProductNumber`, `ProductName` and `Sizes` properties, where the `Sizes` is just the array from `Sizes.value`. We can then convert to a JSON structure with [`ConvertTo-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json?view=powershell-7), keeping the first three levels with `-Depth 3`, and export the result to an output file with [`Out-File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file?view=powershell-7).

```
$json = Get-Content -Path .\data.json | ConvertFrom-Json

& {
    foreach ($object in $json)
    {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            ProductNumber = $object.ProductNumber
            ProductName = $object.ProductName
            Sizes = $object.Sizes.value
        }
    }
} | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 3 | Out-File -FilePath output.json
```

You could probably also integrate the above logic in what you already have, so you don't need to rebuild the JSON in the first place. Unfortunately I can't really show how to do that because all I can see is the JSON you are producing, so I can only recommend a solution to rebuild the JSON to your requirements.

*output.json*

```
[
  {
    "ProductNumber": "EBAGS101-00008",
    "ProductName": "EBAGS101",
    "Sizes": [
      {
        "SizeCode": "XS",
        "UPC": "201112291509"
      },
      {
        "SizeCode": "S",
        "UPC": "201112291510"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "ProductNumber": "EBAGS101-001",
    "ProductName": "EBAGS101",
    "Sizes": [
      {
        "SizeCode": "XS",
        "UPC": ""
      },
      {
        "SizeCode": "S",
        "UPC": "098617106215"
      }
    ]
  } 
]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. The logic you've provided helped me solve the problem. Had to tweak a little the code since my source is flat csv file using the above logic. I'll update my question with the tweaked code.

Comment: @RichardMneyan No worries. I'm glad you found the solution helpful and adaptable to your scenario.

Answer (score 2):

Workaround: `Remove-TypeData -TypeName System.Array`